# How to polar stretch/scale a set of object in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform

Suppose I drawn a set of objects that will fill an angular wedge of approximately 58° of a circumscribed circle.

Now I want to stretch these object so that they fill a wedge of exactly 60°; more formally I want to scale the polar angle of polar coordinates of the control points. [Later I want to replicate these object 6 times to fill an entire circle.]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Draw a 60 degr. reference wedge and put your image there. Warp your image:

Object > Envelope Distort > Make by Warp > Arc, vertical, preview, bend=0

Finally rotate the warped object. Undo and repeat, if not near enough.

[image]

No rotation is needed, if  you position the original and the reference so that the half angle is horizontal The Smokeman sits on a horizontal surface, so it's easier to rotate him back.